# Get file name from headers with DownloadManager in Android

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I'm using DownloadManager to download video files from a url.

The problem is if I use the default folder to download the file I can not see the video in the galery.

Also, If I try to use this method:

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, 'filename');
```

I need to know the file name *before* download which in this case, **I don't**.

And also, I don't have the name of the file in the url.

How can I do to get the file name from the headers and pass the name to the method  setDestinationInExternalPublicDir ? 
Other alternatives?

Comment: "The problem is if I use the default folder to download the file I can not see the video in the galery" -- 
what did you do to make it show up in the Gallery? Did you use `MediaScannerConnnection` and `scanFile()`? Otherwise, it will not show up until the next periodic round of file indexing, which may be a while. "I need to know the file name before download which in this case, I don't" -- then issue an HTTP `HEAD` request or something so that you can get the filename.

Comment: What it doesn't make sense to me is why DonwloadManager doesnt't provide a way to set just the destination folder and keep the name of the file from the server. I'm missing something here? Thanks for your time again.

Comment: That'd be a nice feature, but `DownloadManager` doesn't offer it.

Comment: Getting file name from the download response header? I think this would be a basic feature of a "DownloadManager". It's just frustrating to work with Android at times.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In case anyone want an implementation of doing a HEAD request to get the filename:

```
class GetFileName extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        URL url;
        String filename = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
            con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            con.connect();

            String content = con.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
            String contentSplit[] = content.split("filename=");
            filename = contentSplit[1].replace("filename=", "").replace("\"", "").trim();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        return filename;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So there is no way to do it with the DownloadManager? :( I am downloading files from Google Drive and the only way to extract the file name is reading the headers

Answer (score 4):

Small tip, there is a nice helper method in Android

```
URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, contentType);
```

So after completing the call to the server, getting the contenttype and contentDisposition from the Headers this will try and find the filename from the information.

Comment: A simple and effective solution. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not support filename* value from rfc https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5987

Answer (score 0):

I got into the same problem.I used @rodeleon answer but there was no Content-Disposition in response header. Then I analyzed url header from Chrome dev tools and got 'Location' in response header which contained filename at the end, it was like "b/Ol/fire_mp3_24825.mp3". so instead of using

```
String content = con.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition")
```

I used

```
String content = con.getHeaderField("Location")
```

and at the end in onPostExecute

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        String fileName = result.substring(result.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        // use result as file name
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onPostExecute: " + fileName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Method `URLUtil.guessFileName()` (while not yet knowing about the `Content-Disposition`) and also the meanwhile deprecated class `AsyncTask` are both kinda problematic approaches these days. To properly enqueue the download with the `DownloadManager`:

- One first has to disable "following redirects" in whatever HTTP client (that's the clue).
- Then the first response will be `HTTP 302` (with a `Location` header), instead of `HTTP 200`.
- When fetching that, one will get `HTTP 200` with a `Content-Disposition` header (filename).
- Only then one can enqueue with `DownloadManager` (whilst knowing the  filename already).

Here's an example of mine: [`RepositoryFragment`](https://github.com/syslogic/androidx-github/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/io/syslogic/github/fragment/RepositoryFragment.java#L385) (a GitHub Client).

Answer (score -4):

```
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES, uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

Comment: Does not use headers.