# Get Filename when downloading with file DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am writing a simple snippet to download a file from a local server.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
String filePath= null;
filePath = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
filePath = this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();

HERE-----**//request.setDescription("Downloading GeoJSON").setTitle("filename");**

//request.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse(filePath));
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("Folder", "files");
request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
request.setMimeType("application/octet-stream");
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

I want to set the filename in the title and I also want to save the file with the same filename.

I know we can extract the filename in a `BroadcastReceiver` but that broadcast is received only after the download is finished.

Following is the code of the web service -

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
@Path("/geojson2")
public Response getFile() {
  File file = new File(GEOJSON_FILE_PATH);
  return Response.ok(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
      .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getName()) //optional
      .header("Content-Length", file.length()+"")
      .build();
}
```

The Web Service URL looks like this - 
`http://localhost:8080/NFZ_WS/rest/hello/geojson`

So, my question is how to get the filename while enqueuing the URI. Please tell me if I need to edit the web service.

Comment: Sorry but if you ask to download a file then you know already the name of that file i would think. Please elaborate.

Comment: Please tell how the used url looks like. Filename in te title? Title of what?

Comment: @greenapps : The url looks like this `http://localhost:8080/NFZ_WS/rest/hello/geojson`. I don't get the file name from url.

Comment: Title is for the Notification area.

Comment: You can execute a HEAD statement first followed by a GET. Or not use DownloadManager but do it yourself with a http component.

Comment: @greenapps: Any reference on how to use those HEAD and GET statements?

Comment: Aren't you using a GET statetement now already?

Answer (score -1):

Your DownloadManager currently takes care of the "GET" for you, you do not have to do it explicitly unless you are using the HttpGet,HttpClient classes.  And here is a [link to implement a HEAD statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23069965/get-file-name-from-headers-with-downloadmanager-in-android/23164914#23164914?newreg=0049566aba5140b597913ca728403652) to get the name of file being downloaded from web service.